# How to give an animation effect to a text box?

Tags: html, css

I have a searchbar which is placed at the bottom of the page i want that searchbar to be first hidden so as soon as i scroll down the searchbar should appear through a fade in or fade out effect.

This is my HTML code for searchbar:-

```
 <div class="">
  <div class="container-4 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
      <div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4"></div>
    <input class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4 form-control searchbar" type="text" id="search" placeholder="Discover more about any career you like" />    
    <button (click)="test()" class="icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4"></div>
      </div>     
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The library waypoints does just that. You can view basic examples here: [getting started with waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/getting-started/). With that you have an event when there is being scrolled towards your searchbar in the direction you want. Then you can use fadeIn or something similar from jQuery.

Comment: I'am working on angular 2 will i be able to use this ?

Comment: Not the original one but you can use Angular-waypoints for this: https://github.com/zumba/angular-waypoints

Answer (score 0):

check out this link http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gaeBbN you have to use scroll down event instead of click
with the below code youll get bottom of page event

```
  $(window).scroll(function() {
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
   alert("bottom!");
 }
});
```

Comment: @UtkarshGautam  yes you can check out this example http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/VV2ek/